# Error using parametric type parameters in Julia

Tags: julia

I started by defining a type like this:

```
type MyType{E<:Number, A<:AbstractArray{E, 1}}
  x::A
end
```

That is, MyType holds some type of AbstractArray whose elements are some type of Number.  Julia accepts my type definition, and I can construct instances like this:

```
MyType{Int,Array{Int,1}}([1,2,3])
```

However, when I add another field to my type, I run into a problem.  Defining this type:

```
type MyType2{E<:Number, A<:AbstractArray{E, 1}}
  x::A
  y::E
end
```

gives me this:

```
E not defined
while loading In[1], in expression starting on line 1
```

Why do I get this error?  Is there a work around or another technique I should be using?  My goal is to have both the element type and array type be parameters of my type.  This is to allow my code to work with any number type and with Arrays or SubArrays without the performance penalty that seems to be associated with declaring fields as having abstract types.

Comment: To me it seems like a slightly different question, but it definitely has the same answer.  It is unclear to me whether that means close or don't close.

Comment: Yes I agree the question differs. This is probably why my question didn't pop up on the auto-checker (the subject headings are quite different). But my understanding of StackOverflow policy is that the *answer* determines whether a question is a duplicate. More reading on that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)